# Adding Text Changed Event for Grid View Cell

Tags: c#, gridview

One column of `GridView` contains `TextBox` and I want to add `TextChanged` event for that text box in grid view.

Comment: BartoszKP thanx for editing and making it appropriate :)

Comment: Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: What are you using WinForms or ASP.Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [DataGridView.CellBeginEdit Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellbeginedit.aspx)